# Throw exception without stack trace in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

When you throw an exception in Dart (assuming you don't catch it) the program execution will end showing you the exception and the stack trace. I was wondering if there is any way to do it but without showing the stack trace (you don't want the final user to see it) and using throw.

Note: No, I don't want to catch the expression, I want to terminate the program after throwing the exception showing a message but without the stack trace.

Example:

```
class MyErrors implements Exception{
  var notInt;
  MyErrors(this.notInt);
}


void main(List<String> args) {
  var myErrors = MyErrors("The input wasn't an int, please restart the program");
  throw myErrors.notInt
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand why you would want to do this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to create a program that will start something just when another program is terminated by one of our exceptions for example.

Comment: How would the stacktrace ever make it to the view of a user on a website?

Comment: Please, don't ask the question with other question. @rafaholz has a doubt and if you know the solution, explain it. For me the question is clear. Else, don't add noise ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have `main()` be a giant try/catch, with the rest of your program called from try, and the catch block logging the error/stacktrace for smart people to review, and perhaps the finally block to restart the app?